# Granting permission in postgres

Tags: database, postgresql, privileges, sql-grant

Here is the problem I faced during configuring roles in postgres. Hope someone could help me with it.

I'm trying to create role(for example "read_only_role") that will have the ability to read data from the database(for example "test_database").

What I mean is every user that has role "read_only_role" has the ability to "select" data from "test_database".

But also I want to grant one user from that role with all priviliges according to "test_database".

So after I login as superuser, I run such commands:

1. create user test_user_with_all_priv with password 'somepassword';
2. create role read_only_role with user test_user;
3. create database test_database;
4. revoke all on database test_database from public;
5. grant connect on database test_database to read_only_role;
6. alter database test_database owner to test_user_with_all_priv
7. ALTER GROUP read_only_role add USER some_other_test_user(it is an existing user)

So the problems happen after seventh step. Users that is added to the group have ability not only read data from the database but also insert and delete tables from that database.

Does anyone know what could be the reasons for such issues and how can I fix this?

Thanks

Comment: You are not showing all the commands, so it is hard to say where things are going south. For example, there are no statements to create `test_user` and `read_only_role`.

Comment: There are first two commands responsible for that, I guess?

Comment: That covers `read_only_role`; sorry for my sloppy reading. But where do you create `test_user`? Or is that irrelevant? Anyway, no user in `read_only_role` will have any permissions on any data in `test_database` unless there are additional `GRANT`s or `ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGE`s you didn't show. It is also relevant how the tables and schemas were created, which you do not show.

Comment: Let's assume we have 2 users. "some_other_test_user"(from the 7th step) that was created before creating the "test_database" using first comman. 
And "test_user_with_all_priv" that was created in the 1st  step.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. None of the roles will have any privileges on any tables.

Comment: After I'm creating a role and then look at its properties it says that role inherits rights from the parent role. Maybe this is my problem?

Comment: Perhaps. But since you didn't show which permissions are set on which objects, the question cannot be answered.